# Pentaho Data Integration 9.2 - CPython Script Executor not recognizing Libraries

Tags: python, ubuntu, pentaho, cpython

I am using Pentaho Data Integration (PDI) version 9.2 on Ubuntu and trying to execute a CPython Script using the CPython Script Executor step. However, I am encountering an issue where the logs indicate that some libraries, such as pandas, scikit-learn, and matplotlib, are not installed. I have installed these libraries in the global Python environment on Ubuntu without using a virtual environment, as I couldn't find a way to configure the plugin to use a virtual environment.

The same setup works fine on Windows, but I am struggling to get it to work on Ubuntu. How can I resolve this issue and get the CPython Script Executor to recognize the installed libraries in the global Python environment on Ubuntu? Any help would be appreciated.

I would like to know if there is a way of setting environment variables to CPython Script Executor on PDI for Ubuntu. Or, if there's any other solution.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.